# sorting data by object keys does not work when some of the keys are numeric

Tags: javascript, object

I have object contain data like this

```
const testData = {
        "11": {
            "data": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName"
            }
        },
        "12": {
            "data": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName"
            }
        },
        "00": {
            "data": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName"
            }
        },
        "01": {
            "data": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName"
            }
        },
        "final": {
            "data": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName"
            }
        }
    }
```

i want to sort this data by object keys like `00, 01, 11, 12, final`

i have tried like this but i can not achieve what i want.Any idea would be appreciate?

```
sorted = Object.keys(testData).sort().reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc, [key]: testData[key]
  }), {})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: values who could be indices of arrays are sorted first, then by insertation order. double zero is not an index, as well as values with leading zeros.

Comment: why not take an array? at least an array of keys?

Comment: As per requirement i want to go with object only

Comment: how do you like to access the data?

Comment: [JavaScript does not guarantee order of property keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). [Not even in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties).

Comment: But browser displays content in correct order with out sorting

Answer (score 7):

You cannot. The defined iteration order for JavaScript object keys is as follows:

1. Numeric keys, in ascending numeric order. (this includes strings such as `"11"`, but *not* `"01"`), THEN...
2. String keys which are not numeric, in order of insertion. THEN...
3. Symbol keys, in order of their insertion.

As you can see, regardless of insertion order, numeric keys will always appear first in the iteration order, and always in their numeric order.

In your example, `"11"` and `"12"` will *always end up first*, regardless of what you do.

In general, relying on order with objects (which are essentially unordered dictionaries you access via key), is ill-advised. If order matters, you should be using an array. Alternatively, you can use a `Map`.

Comment: what if i add 0 infront of "11" like this "011". this will sort as we want, after sorting we need to remove first 0 in all keys.

Comment: The moment you have, in your object, the key "11" and the key "01", "11" will always come first no matter what. If you add a padding 0, and then remove it before you put it in the object, you will accomplish nothing. Seriously though, use a Map, or an array.

Comment: can you please provide demo for using map in efficient way.

Comment: if i make "0", "1", "12", "14" something like this, can i expect guarantee order in all browsers

Comment: i have updated my post by adding special character before all keys.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
sorted = Object.keys(testData).sort((a,b) => {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: we can get above result with this `Object.keys(testData).sort()` that is not helpful and i should rotate whole data